# How launch any file using default program using Rust (like Python's `os.startfile()`)

Tags: python, python-3.x, rust, operating-system

Is there a rust method equivalent to `os.startfile()` in python. For example, I need to launch an "mp3 file" using rust. In python it is `os.startfile('audio.mp3')`. This will open default media player and start playing that file. I need to do the same with Rust Language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways that will work over multiple OS platforms (Mac, Windows, and Linux) found so far. I have personally tested it as well.
**Method 1:**
Use `opener` crate ([link](https://crates.io/crates/opener))
On Windows the `ShellExecuteW` Windows API function is used. On Mac the system `open` command is used. On other platforms, the `xdg-open` script is used. The system `xdg-open` is not used; instead a version is embedded within this library.
Use the following code in the `rs file`(`src/main.rs`):

```
// open a file
let result = opener::open(std::path::Path::new("Cargo.toml"));
println!("{:?}", result); // for viewing errors if any captured in the variable result
```

Use the following code in the "Cargo.toml" file in the dependencies section:

```
opener = "0.4.1"
```

**Method 2:**
Use `open` crate ([link](https://crates.io/crates/open))
Use this library to open a path or URL using the program configured on the system. It is equivalent to running one of the following: `open <path-or-url>`(OSX), `start <path-or-url>` (Windows), `xdg-open <path-or-url> || gio open <path-or-url> || gnome-open <path-or-url> || kde-open <path-or-url> || wslview <path-or-url>` (Linux).
Use the following code in the `rs file`(`src/main.rs`):

```
// to open the file using the default application
open::that("Cargo.toml");
// if you want to open the file with a specific program you should use the following
open::with("Cargo.toml", "notepad");
```

Use the following code in the "Cargo.toml" file in the dependencies section:

```
open = "1.7.0"
```

Hope it works to all.

Comment: What is the difference between these two crates, they seem to be solving the exact same problem, and both seem to be maintained?

Answer (score 5):

Python's `os.startfile()` function is only available on Windows, and it's just a wrapper around [`ShellExecuteW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutew) in the Windows API. You can [call this function via the `winapi` crate](https://docs.rs/winapi/0.3.9/winapi/um/shellapi/fn.ShellExecuteW.html).

An easier and more portable solution is using the [`open` crate](https://crates.io/crates/open).

Comment: @SantoK.Thomas The `open` crate looks like it explicitly supports Windows, MacOS, iOS, and other Unix systems through `xdg-open` and others.